# Sort Popular Posts by Views for the Last Week

Tags: loop, meta-query, popular-posts

I'm trying to sort the popular posts so it shows the most visited in the last week, but it hasn't worked. Anyone have an idea of why it isn't working?

```
<?php 

$popularpost = new WP_Query( array (

        'posts_per_page'      => 5,
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
        'meta_key'            => 'sw_post_views_count',
        'orderby'             => 'meta_value_num',
        'order'               => 'DESC',
        'date_query'          => array (
                array (
                        'year' => date( 'Y' ),
                        'week' => date( 'W' ),
                ),
        ),
) );

while( $popularpost->have_posts() ) :
       $popularpost->the_post(); ?>
```

Comment: Please share some of the symptoms of your posted code "not working" - what's happening that isn't supposed to? Review the "[ask]" page of our [help] for more tips to improve your question.

Comment: is this the php file of your plugin ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `strtotime` to compare dates.

```
$start = strtotime('yesterday');
$end = strtotime( '+1 week',$start);

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'meta_key' => 'sw_post_views_count',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'date_query' => array(
        'after' => $end,
        'before' => $start,
    ),
);

$popularpost = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $popularpost->have_posts() ) {

    while ( $popularpost->have_posts() ) {
        $popularpost->the_post();

        // Do your stuffs

    }

}
```

Please note, this will return the posts from last 7 days, not last week.

Comment: Hey, so it won't show the most viewed from the current week, but the week before. Did i get this correctly?

Comment: @Max Yes, that's right.

Comment: ok, but that's not what i need. I need from the current week, or for an example from the last 10 days will work as well..any idea for that?

Comment: @Max I've edited my answer and changed the code to retrieve posts from last 7 days. If that solved your issue, please accept it as the answer.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I've seen that a lot of people search for this, hopefully it will help them as well. Kind regards

Comment: Hey @Abhik, i can't solve this yet. When i take out $start and $end the loop content shows, when it's here, its emtpy..what i did wrong http://codepad.org/64iJJGb0

Comment: Not sure!! Can you try putting `$startingNum <= 5` in a separate conditional check?

Comment: Hi@Abhik, when i replace your $start with $start = strtotime('yesterday -1 day $hour:00'); it works. I've found this somewhere, can you tell me will this work, because with it the loop content shows.

Comment: how to test it ?

Answer (score -2):

If you are looking for plugin then this is simple way to install Plugin: WordPress Popular Posts

Add Shortcode to sidebar:

```
  [wpp range=weekly stats_comments=0 thumbnail_width=30 thumbnail_height=30 thumbnail_selection=usergenerated do_pattern=1 pattern_form={image}]
```

Comment: Personally when making your own theme I would try a build most of the little things like this into your theme just so then it is as heavy on your site

Comment: sorry,I didn't get you

Comment: Something as small as this like showing popular posts shouldn't require a Plugin because it's such a small thing to do and doesn't require much installing a Plugin for this is in my opinion pointless

Comment: okay,did you get a solution or I am find interesting in this question.I want to try

Comment: Oh no I didn't ask the question xD I was just giving my opinion on why he shouldn't use a Plugin to do this - my bad I thought you knew I wasn't asking the question, anyways have a good day (or night) Sir :)

Comment: okay,you are right